# Why can not merge branches on git

Tags: github, merge, branch

So, I was working in a branch called user_authentication, I had done some commits in this branch and now I want to merge it, the problem now is, when I try to merge it says that everything is up to date, if I checkout from this brunch to other on my terminal at Vscode, it backs to the previous version without any implementation, the vscode reads the last version on main branch, and when I back to the user_authentication branch, everything back to the last job done, but not on main brhanc, how can I merge or update my main branch with the codes I had done while I was working at user_authentication branch?

Comment: The sequence you're describing sounds like a normal workflow. Therefore, you must have done something wrong, but it is unclear what.  How did you create the user_authentication branch?

Comment: git checkout -b "user_authentication"

Comment: Seems normal. And yet you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, I found my mistake

I was trying to merge the files from the brach user_authentication once I had to be on main branch.

In my mind I though I should be on the branch I was working to merge, as if I was pushing that to the main branch, ty